# Портфолио для FCC, скролл от div.row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток!

Из-за второго div.row появился скролл вправо, как исправить?

Заключая в container сайт урезается

Прилагаю ссылку на PEN:

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/PmaqQr)

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tvarinsky Klondike</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {      
     $('.activatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("position", "absolute");       
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "200%"}, 500);
        $('.deactivatemenu').animate({ top: "5%"}, 500);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
     }); 
     $('.deactivatemenu').click(function(){
        $('.topmenu').animate({ height: "3rem"}, 500);
        $('.activatemenu').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.deactivatemenu').fadeOut(250);
        $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
        $("html,body").css("overflow-x","hidden");
        $('.deactivatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.activatemenu').css("z-index", "5");
        $('.topmenu').css("z-index", "5");
     }); 
  });

</script>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="topmenu">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="deactivatemenu">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    <p class="mobiletext">Close</p>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">                         
                            <a href="#1" class="mobilemenu">Home</a>
                            <a href="#2" class="mobilemenu">About me</a>
                            <a href="#3" class="mobilemenu">Portfolio</a>
                            <a href="#4" class="mobilemenu">Comments</a>
                            <a href="#5" class="mobilemenu">Contact</a>
                            <a href="https://vk.com/meowwiza" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/I_Tvarinsky/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/budakovivan" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="activatemenu">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    <p class="mobiletext">Menu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-11">
        <nav>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <p class="onheader">TVARINSKY</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                <!--Adaptive Menu-->
                <!--PC menu-->
                <a href="#" class="top bottomline">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="top bottomline">About me</a>
                <a href="#" class="top bottomline">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#" class="top bottomline">Comments</a>
                <a href="#" class="top bottomline">Contact</a>
                <!--PC menu-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-10">
                <div class="icons">
                    <a href="https://vk.com/meowwiza" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/I_Tvarinsky/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/budakovivan" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook topvk iconmargin fa-lg"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5 col-md-offset-4">
          <h1 class="main">TVARINSKY</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
          <h3 class="main">Front-end developer <br>UI/UX designer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-md-offset-5">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up fa-flip-vertical fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="main">About me</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="text">Hello! I'm Ivan.<br> I'm Front-end developer,<br> UI/UX designer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="root col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">My life</p>
        </div>
        <div class="root col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x"></i>
          <p class="onblock">It's worked</p>
        </div>
        <div class="root col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Seems good</p>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal"></div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="main">Portfolio</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="text">Are provided below<br> the works performed by me.<br> You can estimate them.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="movegallery">

      <div class="root col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <img src="img\portfolio\2.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\3.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\4.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\7.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\6.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\5.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\1.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
        <img src="img\portfolio\8.png" class="galleryphoto small" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-4 margin2">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="main pmargin">Testimonials</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="text">Hello! I'm Ivan.<br> I'm Front-end developer,<br> UI/UX designer.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="horizontal2"></div>
      <h4 class="comments">Comments (2)</h4>
      <br><br>
      <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Input message text..." maxlength="300" wrap="hard"></textarea>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

      <!-- Первый комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Ekaterina</p>
      <p class="date">2017.02.11 18:33</p>
      <p class="comment">Excellent work, Ivan! I have executed everything even before the discussed terms,<br> I helped with the database, I imposed, the excellent adaptive web site!</p>
      <!-- Первый комментарий -->

      <!-- Второй комментарий -->
      <p class="commentfont">Nikita</p>
      <p class="date">2016.11.07 21:40</p>
      <p class="comment">Ivan is an excellent expert, I have made everything quickly<br> and qualitatively. P.S. The functionality has been in addition realized
        <BR>which was initially not discussed, but at the same time the performer has made <br>everything and didn't demand a payment top. I recommend!
      </p>

      <!-- Второй комментарий -->

      <!-- Показать еще -->
      <a href="#" class="vmore">View more</a>
      <!-- Показать еще -->

      <div class="horizontal2"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
            <b><p class="onfooter cmargin">TVARINSKY</p></b>
            <br><p class="copyright">&#169; 2017 Tvarinsky dev.</p>
            <br><p class="end">Greetings, Traveler!</p>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

 :active,
 :hover,
 :focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
    cursor: default;
}

 ::selection {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

 ::-moz-selection {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.topmenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9rem;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: auto;
}

.onheader {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

h3.main {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.250em;
  color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  right: 3%;
}

h1.main {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #eee;
  line-height: 0.5;
  margin-top: 40%;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  right: 1.5%;
}

.header {
  background: url('../img/header.png');
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  /* Opera 9.6+ */
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Современные браузеры */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

.fa-long-arrow-up {
  color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  left: 3.5%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 0.35s
}

.fa-long-arrow-up:hover {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

p.main {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.000em;
  color: #404040;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #626060;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

p.text {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.pmargin {
    right: 15%;
}

.fa-heart-o {
  border: 5px solid #242424;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-heart-o:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-toggle-on:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

p.onblock {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.313em;
  color: #404040;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.horizontal2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.galleryphoto:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) blur(0px);
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.galleryphoto {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: 0.35s;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.small {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 25rem;
    margin: 15px;
}

.medium {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 25rem;
    margin: 15px;
}

.big {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 40rem;
    margin: 15px;
}

.movegallery {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    padding-top: 25%;
}

.margin {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.margin2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5.5%;
}

h4.comments {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  color: #676666;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #676666;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-smile-o {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 17px;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  transition: 0.35s;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-smile-o:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-paper-plane {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 17px;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  transition: 0.35s;
  left: 3%;
}

.fa-paper-plane:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

textarea {
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  left: 3%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 53px;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #888585;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.25s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  color: #404040;
  transition: 0.25s;
  height: 83px;
}

.commentfont {
  position: relative;
  color: #249cce;
  font-size: 1.575em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.date {
  position: relative;
  color: #a4a4a4;
  font-size: 1.005em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 6%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.comment {
  position: relative;
  color: #676666;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  left: 5%;
}

.vmore {
  border: 1px solid #575757;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
  left: 40%;
  position: relative;
  color: #575757;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.vmore:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
  color: #249cce;
}


.main2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.000em;
  color: #404040;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7%;
  left: 4%;
}

.iconmargin {
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.topvk {
  color: #e1e1e1 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.35s;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  font-size: 1.650em;
}

.topvk:hover{
    transition: 0.35s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.vk {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  transition: 0.35s;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-vk:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.twitter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.github {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fa-github:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.envelope {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.envelope:hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 7%;
    background: #323232;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.onfooter {
  position: relative;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 20%;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin-top: 20%;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.copyright {
  position: relative;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25%;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.cmargin {
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.onfooter:hover{
    transition: 0.35s;
    color: #249cce;
}

.end {
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: block;
  left: 32%;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: 0.35s;
}


a.top {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobiletext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mobilemenu {
  display: block;
  color: #e6e6e6 !important;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottomline {
    position: relative;
    color: #ff3296;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bottomline:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #249cce;
    content: "";
    transition: width 0.2s;
}
.bottomline:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.bottomline:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.fa-bars {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    position: relative;
}

.fa-times {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    position: relative;
}

.menubg {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #404040;
}

.deactivatemenu {
    display: none;
}

.activatemenu {
    display: inline;
}

/* ПК */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fa-bars, .mobiletext {
        display: none;
    } 
 }

/* Планшеты */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    a.top, .bottomline, .onheader {
        display: none;
    }
    a.top {
        display: block;
    }
    .line {
        display: inline;
    }
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .topmenu, .mobiletext, .icons {
        display: none;
    }
 }

/* Телефоны и планшеты */
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 500px) { 
    a.top, .bottomline, .onheader, .icons {
        display: none;
    }
    h1.main {margin-left:15%;}
    .header {
      -moz-background-size: 400%;
      /* Firefox 3.6+ */
      -webkit-background-size: 400%;
      /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
      -o-background-size: 400%;
      /* Opera 9.6+ */
      background-size: 400%;
      /* Современные браузеры */
      height: 100%;}

    .pmargin {
        right: 0%;
    }

    .line {
        display: none;
    }

    a.top{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .fa-heart-o, .fa-toggle-on .fa-thumbs-o-up {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
 }

/* Маленькие телефоны */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    a.top, .bottomline, .onheader, .icons {
        display: none;
    }
    h1.main {
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-top: 60%;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: left;
    }
    h3.main {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-left:5%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .header {
      -moz-background-size: 175%;
      /* Firefox 3.6+ */
      -webkit-background-size: 175%;
      /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
      -o-background-size: 175%;
      /* Opera 9.6+ */
      background-size: 175%;
      /* Современные браузеры */
      height: 40%;}
    .line {
        display: none;
    }

    .vmore {
        left: 32.5%;
    }

    .topmenu {
        height: 3rem;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .fa-bars {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .fa-times {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .fa-long-arrow-up{
        display: none;
    }

    .iconmargin {
        margin-left: 8%;
    }

    .pmargin {
        right: 0%;
    }

    .onheader {
        background: #303030;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    p.main {
        margin-top: 5%;
        font-size: 2.250em;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }

    p.text {
        margin-left: 10%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .fa-heart-o, .fa-toggle-on, .fa-thumbs-o-up {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .horizontal {
        left: 0%;
    }
     .comment {
        max-width: 28rem;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 60%;
    }



 }
.root{
  text-align:center;
}
.root p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: добавьте весь код сюда, из за какого именно div.row? где появляется скоролл? при каких условиях? как должно быть? как не должно быть? скрин?

Comment: что вы заключаете в container? почему?

Comment: @kizoso в container заключил весь контент сайта кроме футера и шапки, обновил топик